# Discord.js project folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, discord.js, directory-structure

I'm making a discord bot using [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/). A lot of complicated features will be implemented soon and a structured system would be truly beneficial. Here are the contents of the project directory:

**Files:**

- index.js
- config.js
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- .gitignore
- winston-logger.js

**Directories:**

- commands
- logs
- node_modules

---

Right now, the project folder is quite messy, and any help with how such a folder could be structured would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the code to actually make the structure work or just the structure layout?

```
Files:

index.js
config.json (json not js)
package.json
package-lock.json
.gitignore

Folders:

commands
events
utils
logs
node_modules
```

If you are asking how to make the structure work, for commands and events, just look up a handler for each, for logs it depends how that works

Comment: Well, I mostly think about making it organized, clear and all around logical. It’s like having a well commented file - not necessary, but really useful.